# How do I add a file to a exe

Tags: c#, file, embed, exe

I have a program that plays a sound but if I run it on a different computer it says that the file isn't found how do I attach the file onto the exe so when someone plays the exe it will still be able to play?

Comment: Generally you don't.
You add it as resources and package it up, (possibly with a installer)
I am interested to know if this is possible (making a stand alone exe, with sound)

Comment: If you want single file solution http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+add+resource+msdn  gives you [How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) with detailed step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Packaging your project files create a folder inside your project folder to hold your content data (text - pictures - videos - sound .. etc) and then supply your code with the relative path of your target file rather than the absolute path .

for example : instead of

```
    string path = "c:\Projects\ProjectFolder\FileName";
```

do it like that :

```
     string currentDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
     string fullPath = currentDir + "ContentFolder/FileName.mp3(or whatever)";
```

Edit :

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Will be the application root directory, not the bin subfolder - which is probably what you usually want. In a client app, it will be the directory containing the main executable.

Comment: +0: `CurrentDirectory` is very dangerous approach. Make sure to search for similar questions on how to read files from output (bin and like) folders.

Comment: Actually there are a lot of ways for doing the job , thanks for the advice cause i needed to revise the difference rather than writing the first answer that came to my mind

Comment: +1. thanks for edit - `BaseDirectory` is much more reliable approach to get location of files (as exe can be launched with any current directory including).

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting to embed your wave file into your program, go to your Project Properties --> Resources --> Select Audio as the type then select Add Resource and select your Audio File. This will add the Audio File to your Resources Directory. Once you have done this you can right click on the File in the Resources folder and select Properties and change the Build Action to `Embedded Resource`.

To access the file you would do something like this:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.tada);
sp.Play();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go the properties of the file, and under Copy to output Directory select, copy if newer

[image]

You can package the EXE with your c# program when you are ready to release it with an installer

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the source code,I suggest

http://m.instructables.com/id/How-to-create-portable-app/?ALLSTEPS

It is about creating new exe archive containing old exe+new files you want to merge. When you call that new exe, it runs your old exe, but also contain your music files You can follow step4 and 5

Put your exe and music files into the same folder and compress them through that method

Comment: Just link is not a good format of answer for SO. You need to either make it comment OR provide summary of the link that is enough to understand what it is talking about.

Comment: +1 now: reasonable approach to create installer... About post: don't forget to remove signature from the post - you already have it as user name... And check if you need "follow step4 and 5 repeated twice".

Comment: Thanks @AlexiLevenkov, Now I can comment. You are very generous.